# How do you redesign the following boolean expressions using only NAND/NOR gates?

Tags: boolean-logic, nor

1. Redesign F = A or (~B and D) or (B and ~D) or (~B and C) using only NAND gates.
2. Redesign Y = (~A and B) or ~D using all NOR gates.

For the first question, I got to ~(~(~A NAND ~(~B and D)) NAND ~(B and ~D)) NAND ~(~B and C) but cannot figure out what to do next.

I am completely confused by the second question.

Comment: https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator might help